# How to indicate things that you should listen for in Musescore?

Tags: theory, notation, sheet-music, musescore

Some people have complained about my arrangements being hard to understand when only viewing your part sheet. Because of that, I'd like to somehow indicate that a certain part should not be played, but instead being listened to.

Consider this:

[image]

Here I want the lower part to listen for the higher, so I would like to copy those notes. Like this:

[image]

But how should I indicate that those note should not be played? One way would be if those notes were considerably smaller, like grace notes, but I have not found a way to create a complete melody with grace notes since you need to attach all grace notes to real notes.

EDIT:

Found a solution, but I hope for better answers. My solution cannot possibly be the most convenient way.

Answer (score 4):

You're asking for 'cues'.  See example below, borrowed from the [Wikipedia item on that topic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_note)  You'll see that the main part retains its full notation, rests and all, the smaller cue notes are labelled with the name of the instrument that plays them.

[image]

The more advanced notation programs (Sibelius, Finale) have a 'Paste as cue' function that automatically puts the cues in an otherwise unused Voice, hides the cues in the Full Score, shows them in the Parts, turns off playback etc.   MuseScore can achieve all this, but you'll have to do it manually.

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Turned out the solution was pretty simple.

To change the size of the note heads, select the notes and press F8 and the press the button notes. Now check the checkbox "small". Now it looks like this:

[image]

In the same inspector you get when pressing F8, where you can change the size of the note heads, you can also simply uncheck a checkbox called play. This will make those notes silent.

Comment: You're nearly there.  But reinstate the (full-size) rests under the cue notes and label then with the voice or instrument they represent.

Comment: @LaurencePayne I tried that, but it looked like a complete mess. If you know how to do it, please add an own answer and provide a picture.

Comment: OK.  I've extended my answer with a MuseScore example.